# Jquery: How do I count all the rows in a section and display the count

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a search that allows users to search a table row for a string. If the row doesn't contain that string then it is hidden.

However, I am using Bootstrap's Collapseable Accordian: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

I would like to be able to count how many rows are displaying in the header of each group. But my total seems to be concatenating. You can see some sections have multiple tables, so I'm only counting the rows.

I'm new-ish at Jquery. I don't know its full power yet, so help is appreciated.

My code:

```js
/*
 1. Get users search string & Display only rows that match
 2. Display how many results are in each
 */

$( document ).ready(function() {
    // on search display the relevant rows
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $("tr").each(function(index) {
            $row = $(this);
            var id = $row.find("td:first").text().toLowerCase();
            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        });

        countRows();
    });
});

function countRows() {
    $(".panel-catalog").each(function(){
        // count the rows in all tables under each .panel-catalog that weren't hidden from the above code.
        var total = $(this).find('tr').length;
        // add count next to title
        $(this).find('.rowcount').text(total);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="search">Search</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-group accordion-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
  <div class="panel panel-catalog">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#procedures" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="procedures">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    Procedures    <span class="rowcount"></span>              </a>
                </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="procedures" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
      <div class="panel-body">


        <!-- Display Downloads BEGIN -->
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Alpha-Amino Nitrogen by NOPA</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Alpha-Amino-Nitrogen-by-NOPA0821081.pdf" target="_blank">Alpha-Amino Nitrogen by NOPA</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 86 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Brix: Hydrometer and Refractometer</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Brix-Hydrometer-and-Refractometer0818081.pdf" target="_blank">Brix: Hydrometer and Refractometer</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 43 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Cold and Heat Stability</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Procedure-for-Cold-and-Heat-Stability0818081.pdf" target="_blank">Cold and Heat Stability</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 26 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Color (Wine, Juice, and Concentrate)</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Color-Wine-Juice-Concentrate0818081.pdf" target="_blank">Color (Wine, Juice, and Concentrate)</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
                <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Juice Processing</span> 
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 26 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Managing 'Stuck' Malolactic Fermentations with Viniflora®</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Managing-Stuck-MLF-with-Viniflora-11.091.pdf" target="_blank">Managing 'Stuck' Malolactic Fermentations with Viniflora®</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 87 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Pectinase Enzyme Analysis</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Pectinase-Enzyme-Analysis0818081.pdf" target="_blank">Pectinase Enzyme Analysis</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 25 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">pH Determination</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Procedure-for-pH-Determination0818081.pdf" target="_blank">pH Determination</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 24 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Restarting Stuck and Sluggish Fermentations</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Restarting-Stuck-and-Sluggish-Fermentation1.pdf" target="_blank">Restarting Stuck and Sluggish Fermentations</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 524 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">RS Determination Using Clinitest Tabs</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/RS-Determination-Clinitest-Tabs0818081.pdf" target="_blank">RS Determination Using Clinitest Tabs</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 32 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">SO2 (Free) Ripper Procedure</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/SO2-Free-Ripper-Procedure0818081.pdf" target="_blank">SO2 (Free) Ripper Procedure</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 26 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Sulfide Dectection Kit Instructions</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Sulfide-Detection-Kit-Instructions1.pdf" target="_blank">Sulfide Dectection Kit Instructions</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 65 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Total Acidity (TA) Procedure</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Procedure-for-TA-Total-Acidity0818081.pdf" target="_blank">Total Acidity (TA) Procedure</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 28 kB</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- Display Downloads END -->






        <!--                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/downloads/procedures/" class="btn btn-primary">View ALL forms &amp; downloads for Procedures.</a>-->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-catalog">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#technical-data-sheets" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="technical-data-sheets" class="collapsed" ;="">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    Technical Data Sheets                  </a>
                </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="technical-data-sheets" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2"><span class="rowcount"></span>
      <div class="panel-body">


        <!-- Display Downloads BEGIN -->
        <!-- Display Downloads END -->


        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <h4>Enological Tannins</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Grap'tan E Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/TAN-E-Data-Sheet1.pdf" target="_blank">Grap'tan E Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 67 kB</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Grap'tan PC Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/TAN-PC-Data-Sheet1.pdf" target="_blank">Grap'tan PC Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 65 kB</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Grap'tan S Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/TAN-S-Data-Sheet1.pdf" target="_blank">Grap'tan S Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 63 kB</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Grap'tan V Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/TAN-V-PDS1.pdf" target="_blank">Grap'tan V Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 337 kB</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Enzymes</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Bioseutica Lysozyme Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/lysozyme_sheet_v5_HR1.pdf" target="_blank">Bioseutica Lysozyme Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 421 kB</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Filtration</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Carbon Filter Media - Carbac Filter Sheet Series Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Carbac-PDS-0615111.pdf" target="_blank">Carbon Filter Media - Carbac Filter Sheet Series Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Brewing</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Distilling</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Juice Processing</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 316 kB</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Cellu-Flo FB PDS 100411</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Cellu-Flo040309.pdf" target="_blank">Cellu-Flo FB PDS 100411</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Brewing</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Distilling</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Juice Processing</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 3 MB</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Fining Agents</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>KICK Carrageenan Kettle Finings</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Malolactic Bacteria, Fermentation Nutrition and Aids</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>MicroElements Nutrients</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Yeast</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Yeast Nutrition</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
        </ul>




        <!--                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/forms-downloads/" class="btn btn-primary">View ALL forms &amp; downloads for .</a>-->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-catalog">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#application-briefs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="application-briefs" class="collapsed" ;="">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    Application Briefs                  </a>
                </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="application-briefs" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading3">
      <div class="panel-body">


        <!-- Display Downloads BEGIN -->
        <!-- Display Downloads END -->


        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <h4>Brewing Color</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Filter Cartridges</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Yeast</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
        </ul>




        <!--                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/downloads/application-briefs/" class="btn btn-primary">View ALL forms &amp; downloads for Application Briefs.</a>-->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Brandi, I've edited this to do what I think you are wanting.

First you need to add a span tag to your H4.panel-title to put the number in. You can't just append it. Because you need to be able to replace it when the number changes. see the span.rowcount in the snippit below.

```
<h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#application-briefs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="application-briefs" class="collapsed" ;="">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                Application Briefs                  </a>
      <span class="rowcount"></span>
            </h4>

</div>
```

Next, You need to use a class to hide the rows rather than $row.hide() because you need a way to count the rows that are going to be visible when the accordion spins open. And using the (':visible') won't work when they are hidden with the accordion

```
tr.hideme { display: none; }
```

Then you pull your row count code out into a function that gets called on page load and inside your $('search').on('keyup' function.

The full working code is below and here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/za7pcv9t/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // on search display the relevant rows
  $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $("tr").each(function(index) {
          $row = $(this);
          var id = $row.find("td:first").text().toLowerCase();
          if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
            $row.addClass('hideme');
          } else {
            $row.removeClass('hideme');
          }
        });
      setRowCounts();
    });

   setRowCounts();


});

function setRowCounts(){
     //count how many rows
    $(".panel-catalog").each(function() {
      // count the rows in all tables under each .panel-catalog that weren't hidden from the above code.
      var total = $(this).find('tr').not('.hideme').length;
      // add count next to title
      $(this).find('span.rowcount').text(total);
    });
}
```

Comment: fantasic! I am a little closer. I updated my code. It's now showing total rows but it's not updating the new row count. If you type "col" in the search it still shows 12 instead of 2. It's in the 'keyup' function. And I dont actually see the rows in the DOM, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: no no wait. I do see the rows in the dom. well crap.

Comment: @BrandiEvans - I think I understand what you are trying to get to now. Check the edited answer above and checkout the fiddle. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //first cashe the rows and panels.  if they are not dynamically added
  //or created to the page, this saves some dom lookups and increases performance
  var $allRows = $("tr");
  var $panels = $(".panel-catalog");
  
  // on search display the relevant rows
  $("#search").on("input", function() {
    //get the value, no need to wrap it
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    
    //assume everything doesn't match, hide everything
    $allRows.hide();
    
    //find all the things that do match, that we need to show
    $allRows.filter(function(index){
        //instead of doing $(this) we can use eq() to get the already wrapped element
        var $row = $allRows.eq(index);
      
        //here we find the first cell and get the text of it to compare against
        //if the indexOf returns > -1 it will return true which will cause the
        //element to be returned from the filter to be operated on (to show it)
        return ( $row.find('td:first').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1 );
    }).show();

    //count how many rows
    $panels.each(function(index) {
        var $panel = $panels.eq(index);
      
        //here there are multiple panel-title elements and you want to set the
        //value of the one related to the particular panel.  so we find the one
        //in the panel rather than a global .panel-title fine, which would
        //find them all
        // :visible is a matcher that filters out any element that is not display hidden
        //we set the html, rather than appending, to replace the entire value
        $panel.find('.panel-title a').html( $panel.find('tr:visible').length );
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="search">Search</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-group accordion-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
  <div class="panel panel-catalog">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#procedures" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="procedures">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    Procedures                  </a>
                </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="procedures" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
      <div class="panel-body">


        <!-- Display Downloads BEGIN -->
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Alpha-Amino Nitrogen by NOPA</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Alpha-Amino-Nitrogen-by-NOPA0821081.pdf" target="_blank">Alpha-Amino Nitrogen by NOPA</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 86 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Brix: Hydrometer and Refractometer</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Brix-Hydrometer-and-Refractometer0818081.pdf" target="_blank">Brix: Hydrometer and Refractometer</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 43 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Cold and Heat Stability</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Procedure-for-Cold-and-Heat-Stability0818081.pdf" target="_blank">Cold and Heat Stability</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 26 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Color (Wine, Juice, and Concentrate)</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Color-Wine-Juice-Concentrate0818081.pdf" target="_blank">Color (Wine, Juice, and Concentrate)</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
                <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Juice Processing</span> 
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 26 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Managing 'Stuck' Malolactic Fermentations with Viniflora®</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Managing-Stuck-MLF-with-Viniflora-11.091.pdf" target="_blank">Managing 'Stuck' Malolactic Fermentations with Viniflora®</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 87 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Pectinase Enzyme Analysis</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Pectinase-Enzyme-Analysis0818081.pdf" target="_blank">Pectinase Enzyme Analysis</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 25 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">pH Determination</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Procedure-for-pH-Determination0818081.pdf" target="_blank">pH Determination</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 24 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Restarting Stuck and Sluggish Fermentations</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Restarting-Stuck-and-Sluggish-Fermentation1.pdf" target="_blank">Restarting Stuck and Sluggish Fermentations</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 524 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">RS Determination Using Clinitest Tabs</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/RS-Determination-Clinitest-Tabs0818081.pdf" target="_blank">RS Determination Using Clinitest Tabs</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 32 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">SO2 (Free) Ripper Procedure</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/SO2-Free-Ripper-Procedure0818081.pdf" target="_blank">SO2 (Free) Ripper Procedure</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 26 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Sulfide Dectection Kit Instructions</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Sulfide-Detection-Kit-Instructions1.pdf" target="_blank">Sulfide Dectection Kit Instructions</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 65 kB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="display:none;">Total Acidity (TA) Procedure</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Procedure-for-TA-Total-Acidity0818081.pdf" target="_blank">Total Acidity (TA) Procedure</a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">
              </td>
              <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                PDF – 28 kB</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- Display Downloads END -->






        <!--                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/downloads/procedures/" class="btn btn-primary">View ALL forms &amp; downloads for Procedures.</a>-->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-catalog">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#technical-data-sheets" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="technical-data-sheets" class="collapsed" ;="">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    Technical Data Sheets                  </a>
                </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="technical-data-sheets" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
      <div class="panel-body">


        <!-- Display Downloads BEGIN -->
        <!-- Display Downloads END -->


        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <h4>Enological Tannins</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Grap'tan E Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/TAN-E-Data-Sheet1.pdf" target="_blank">Grap'tan E Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 67 kB</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Grap'tan PC Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/TAN-PC-Data-Sheet1.pdf" target="_blank">Grap'tan PC Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 65 kB</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Grap'tan S Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/TAN-S-Data-Sheet1.pdf" target="_blank">Grap'tan S Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 63 kB</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Grap'tan V Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/TAN-V-PDS1.pdf" target="_blank">Grap'tan V Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 337 kB</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Enzymes</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Bioseutica Lysozyme Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/lysozyme_sheet_v5_HR1.pdf" target="_blank">Bioseutica Lysozyme Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 421 kB</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Filtration</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Carbon Filter Media - Carbac Filter Sheet Series Product Data Sheet</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Carbac-PDS-0615111.pdf" target="_blank">Carbon Filter Media - Carbac Filter Sheet Series Product Data Sheet</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Brewing</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Distilling</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Juice Processing</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 316 kB</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="display:none;">Cellu-Flo FB PDS 100411</td>
                  <td style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Cellu-Flo040309.pdf" target="_blank">Cellu-Flo FB PDS 100411</a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <span class="label label-primary">Winemaking</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Brewing</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Distilling</span>  <span class="label label-primary">Juice Processing</span> 
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:150px; text-align:center;">
                    PDF – 3 MB</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Fining Agents</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>KICK Carrageenan Kettle Finings</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Malolactic Bacteria, Fermentation Nutrition and Aids</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>MicroElements Nutrients</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Yeast</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Yeast Nutrition</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
        </ul>




        <!--                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/forms-downloads/" class="btn btn-primary">View ALL forms &amp; downloads for .</a>-->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-catalog">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#application-briefs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="application-briefs" class="collapsed" ;="">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    Application Briefs                  </a>
                </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="application-briefs" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading3">
      <div class="panel-body">


        <!-- Display Downloads BEGIN -->
        <!-- Display Downloads END -->


        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <h4>Brewing Color</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Filter Cartridges</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Yeast</h4>

            <!-- Display Downloads Sub BEGIN -->
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            </table>
            <!-- Display Downloads Sub END -->

          </li>
        </ul>




        <!--                    <a href="http://privateurl.com/downloads/application-briefs/" class="btn btn-primary">View ALL forms &amp; downloads for Application Briefs.</a>-->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Why does everyone do this kind of thing:  $panels.each(function(index) { var $panel = $panels.eq(index);    Is no one aware that the 'each' function will pass 2 parameters to your function. The first is the index as shown but the second is the actual object. So you could do $panels.each(function(index, panel){.

Comment: panel passed in on the each is the raw element.  if you want to do jquery operations off of it you would have to re-wrap it and reincur that cost.  If your not doing jquery operations off of it that would work, but in this case she is doing follow up finders, so reusing the already wrapped element is preferred.

Comment: @Taplar - I see your point. It is true that you would have to convert it to the jQuery object to run jQuery operations. Another quick comment on your answer. She's putting these counts inside bootstrap accordion headers. Unless I'm missing something your "$panel.find('tr:visible').length" is going to show zero for all of the accordions that are currently collapsed.

Comment: @GreggDuncan - Ah, I missed that part, :(